# Finding the radii of an ellipse from the intersection of a plane and a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, plane-curves, spheres

I'm trying to solve the following problem, regarding Stokes Theorem:

> $F = z i + xj + yk $; C the curve of intersection of the plane
>   $x + y + z = 0$ and the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ [Hint: Recall
>   that the area of an ellipse $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$.]

I know that whenever we have a plane that intersects with sphere, this intersection produces a curve that has the form of an ellipse. Knowing this how can you determine the radii of said ellipse?

Comment: A plane and sphere intercept in a circle. Pretty sure of this.

Comment: An ellipse is a conic section.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the intersection of these two surfaces.

Either say: 
$z = -x-y$ and plug this into the the equation for the sphere.
$x^2 + y^2 + x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = 1\\
2x^2 + 2y^2 + 2xy = 1$

Which is an elipse rotated 45 degrees off from standard,  and rotate it back if you wish...This is the projection of the intersection on the xy plane.

Or say.  $(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},0)$ and $(0,\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2})$ lie on the intersection of the two surfaces.

$(x,y,z) = (\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},0) \cos t + (0,\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}) \sin t$

or

$x = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \cos t\\ y = -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \cos t +\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \sin t\\ z = -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \sin t$

Is a parametric equation of the curve.

To apply stokes theorem...

$\int (-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \sin t)(-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \sin t) + (\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \cos t)(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \sin t +\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \cos t)+(-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \cos t +\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \sin t)(-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \cos t) dt =
\iint curl F \,dA$

And you can use the hemisphere or the circle and get the same answer.  I would use the circle.